# Where is the JobManager on embedded Flink instances?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am developing an application with multiple (micro)services.
I am using Flink (over Kafka) to stream messages between the services. Flink is embedded in the Java applications, each running in a separate docker container.
This is the first time I'm trying Flink and after reading the docs I still have a feeling I'm missing something basic.

Who is managing the jobs?
Where is the JobManager running?
How do  I monitor the processing?

Thanks,

Moshe

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qWs_rMUKPQ) by Stephan Ewen at Flink Forward 2016. It explains the current Apache Flink architecture (10:45) for different deployments as well as future goals.

In general, the JobManager is managing Flink jobs and TaskManagers execute your job consisting of multiple tasks. How the components are orchestrated depends on your deployment (local, Flink cluster, YARN, Mesos etc.).

The best tool for monitor your processing is the Flink Web UI at port 8081 by default, it offers different metrics for debugging and monitoring (e.g. monitoring [checkpointing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/checkpoint_monitoring.html) or [back-pressure](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/back_pressure.html)).

Comment: Flink is executed in each one of the services, managing the messages that are passed through Kafka. The services themselves are isolated Java processes (each in a different docker container). I am currently running no JobManager explicitly. I must? I need? If true, how does the JobManager find all the instances?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-contrib/docker-flink#deploy